# Is this dictionary function thread-safe (ConcurrentHashMap+AtomicInteger)?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, atomic, compare-and-swap

I need to write a really simple dictionary which will be append only. The dictionary will be shared between many threads. When any thread calls `getId` I want to make sure the same id is always returned for the same word, i.e. there should be only one id for any unique word.

Now obviously I could just synchronize access to the `getId` method, but that is not very fun. So I wondered if there was a lock-free way to achieve this.

In particular, I am wondering about the thread safety of using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent`. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) for the interface `ConcurrentMap` says:

> The default implementation may retry these steps when multiple threads attempt updates including potentially calling the mapping function multiple times.

From that description, it is not clear to me if that means that the mapping function *might* be called more than once for the **same** key?

If that is the case (i.e. the mapper might be called more than once for the same key), then I think the following code is most likely not thread-safe as it could call `getAndIncrement` more than once for the same key (i.e. word).

If that is not the case, then I think the following code is thread-safe. Can anyone confirm?

```
public class Dictionary {
    private final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> words =
             new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public int getId(final String word) {
        return words.computeIfAbsent(word, this::newId);
    }

    private int newId(final String word) {
        return index.getAndIncrement();
    }  
}
```

Comment: AFAICS This should be thread safe, but it is not guaranteed that there is no gaps in the numbers assigned.

Comment: @PeterLawrey could you explain how there would be gaps in the numbers?

Comment: "The default implementation may retry these steps" means that there is a risk multiple thread attempting to add the same word, could call `newId` concurrently, but only one value will use used and returned.  This would leave value(s) unused.

Comment: Hmm... that is interesting. As long as one word only ever has one unique id, then I think I can live with non-contiguous ids. I guess it just means that my id space could be exhausted faster under heavy concurrency.

Comment: If you use AtomicLong instead it will last 4 billion times longer.  The missing ids should be rare and would have to be that the same word is added in two threads at the same moment.

Comment: I just rechecked the javadoc, whilst ConcurrentMap does say that "The default implementation may retry these steps" the javadoc for ConcurrentHashMap seems to say that the mapping function will only be called once - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction- What do you think?

Comment: You could be right, but I wouldn't rely on it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is guaranteed to be thread safe by the `ConcurrentMap` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) (emphasis mine):

> Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value [*happen-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) actions subsequent to the **access or removal** of that object from the ConcurrentMap in another thread.

The `ConcurrentHashMap` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) has an example similar to yours:

> A ConcurrentHashMap can be used as scalable frequency map (a form of histogram or multiset) by using LongAdder values and initializing via computeIfAbsent. For example, to add a count to a `ConcurrentHashMap<String,LongAdder> freqs`, you can use `freqs.computeIfAbsent(k -> new LongAdder()).increment();`

While this uses `computeIfAbsent`, it should be analogous to `putIfAbsent`.

The `java.util.concurrent` package Javadoc talks about "happens-before":

> [Chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) defines the *happens-before* relation on memory operations such as reads and writes of shared variables. The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation *happens-before* the read operation.

And the Language Specification says:

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

So your code should be thread safe.

Comment: Do you agree with @peterlawrey about some ids being skipped?

Comment: @adamretter When the `ConcurrentMap#compute*` methods say "may retry", it refers to the `default` implementations not being synchronized/atomic, but `ConcurrentHashMap` overrides all these `default` methods and guarantee that "the entire method invocation is performed atomically", as you noted. Also, if the mapping functions of these methods *were* retried, then the "frequency map" example of the `ConcurrentHashMap` Javadoc would be broken. Therefore, I do not think there will be gaps in your IDs.